# javascript - Finding remainder of integer not working

Tags: javascript

I want to find (using JS) the greatest 3-digit number that

leaves a remainder of 1 when divided by 2

leaves a remainder of 2 when divided by 3

leaves a remainder of 3 when divided by 4

leaves a remainder of 4 when divided by 5

This is my code:

```
var bool = false;
for(var i = 999; bool == true; i = (i - 1)) {
   if(i % 2 == 1 && i % 3 == 2 && i % 4 == 3 && i % 5 == 4) {
      bool = true;
      alert(i);
   }
}
```

But it did not work (somehow there was no error messages, and the alert did not show up). So how can I find that 3-digit number? Thanks.

Comment: to be sure to understand : you need to find a number matching all this ? or 5 numbers ?

Comment: @Bartdude A number matching all this. 1 number only.

Comment: In the meantime you got your answer :-) 1 more advice though : ALWAYS be sure that your loop will end somehow. Ideally when using a for loop, you should always have your index somewhere in the loop-ending condition. I like your approach of breaking it as soon as you got your result though, that's a good thinking !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop continuation condition for your loop is `bool == true`, which is false when the loop starts and so the loop will never execute. Use this instead:

```
for(var i = 999; i > 0 && !bool; i = (i - 1)) {
```

or this to strictly obey the "three-digit number" requirement:

```
for(var i = 999; i >= 100 && !bool; i = (i - 1)) {
```

I'd also suggest finding a better variable name than `bool`. `found` would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Your breaking condition is wrong here change it to:

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2X2B4/1/)

```
var bool = false;
for(var i = 999; !bool; i--) {

   if(i % 2 == 1 && i % 3 == 2 && i % 4 == 3 && i % 5 == 4) {
      bool = true;
      alert(i);
   }
}
```